# Visual Studio test discovery not picking up Test in a referenced DLL

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, nuget, t4, test-explorer

I have a local nuget package which contains a single test.  The test is decorated with [TestClass] and it's test method is [TestMethod].

The reason this is a nuget package is because this test will be brought in to any test projects in order to test that a t4 transform has occurred in the referenced assemblies.  The t4 template generates classes dynamically and I want the test to run to verify the t4 template has been executed (using reflection to make sure the generated classes have the expected methods)

When I reference the nuget package, the Visual Studio Test Explorer never displays the test.  I was under the impression that VS reflected over the types in the assemblies to build it's test list, but that seems to be an incorrect assumption.

Is there a configuration setting or something that I am missing in order to have the test discovered?

Thank you,
Jason

Comment: Can you share me your nugget package which contains the test? Maybe you could share me the detailed steps about how you really create the specific package and the test project in your side. So I could repro this issue in my side.

Comment: I have a zipped up solution.  Where should I send it?

Comment: you could upload it to the one drive: https://onedrive.live.com/. And share the link here.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgbvxdwT_9zjg-FccdMFpOG-nXoynQ

Comment: run nuget pack MyMainProject.NugetTest.csproj and then try to add a reference to that package in the MyMainProject.Tests.  You should see that the test in the nuget package won't show up in Test Explorer

Comment: If I open ConsoleApplication31.sln file, it shows that "MyMainProject(unavaliable)" and the MyMainProject.Tests project, do you change the project name or others?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Test Explorer can only run tests from multiple test projects in a solution and from test classes that are part of the production code projects.

There are two workarounds for your scenario:

1. [Run the test from command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486(v=vs.120).aspx).
2. Instead of placing the generated dll file in the nuget package, placing the test class file in the "content" folder of the nuget package. This will add the test class file to your project when install the nuget package and then Test Explorer will detect the tests after building the solution.

Comment: Is there a bug or open issue to address this on MS side. It is a very frustrating bug for me, as I so many nuget packages with tests built in them